# gams specify network of flux with lots of zeros (sparse matrix)

Tags: gams-math

I tried to use gams to find flow of material across network of nodes.  I defined

```
set edge(i,n,nn);
positive variable flux(i,n,nn);

y.up(i,n,nn)$( not edge(i,n,nn)) = 0;
```

My intention is to define 3D matrix of variable for `flux` of matrial i from node n to nn, then use the set `edge` which specifies which of complete graph can have mass of flow.

This apparently working but when i tried to save y into gdx file, i have lots of lots of zeros.  I only need subset of y where edge(i,n,nn) is true.

How can i subset the y when saving gdx file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store things in a reduced parameter:

```
Parameter yLevel(i,n,nn);
yLevel(i,n,nn)$edge(i,n,nn) = y.l(i,n,nn);
execute_unload 'result.gdx' yLevel;
```

Just a note: Do you really need the complete y(i,n,nn)? This could be huge dependent on the size of the indexing sets. Or could you alternatively modify your model to just use y(i,n,nn)$edge(i,n,nn)?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, i will try that.  As for the complete matrix, it is totally unnecessary.  I want to do something more sparse but using y.up=0 is the way i came up with...  One of equations calculates, for example, mass balance equation has `x(i,n) =e=  sum(nn, y(i,n,nn)) + sum(nn,y(i,nn,n))` , meaning that mass of `i` flows in/out of node n are calculated by sum flux `y`.  I guess i should say `sum(nn,y(i,nn,n)$edge(i,n,nn))`?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest to use $edge(i,n,nn) wherever you use y(i,n,nn). This way, the unnecessary variables won't get generated at all (and then, you do not need to store just parts of it in a parameter anymore).

Comment: Glad you mentioned about reducing size of problem!  That's what I needed!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad, that it helped!